# Android reading from InStream is never resolved (No data read, no crash)

Tags: android, stream

I have a device here that I can send a status request command to, and then I read it using

bytes = mmInStream.read(statusBuffer);

I'm having trouble when it changes it's status though. Sometimes I will get back the current status, other times the program will hang on that line and not do anything else. It doesn't crash, move onto the next line or anything. I can only move on by turning off the device and severing the connection.

We have a blackberry torch here that does not have this error at all so it must be my code.

Can anyone give me some troubleshooting tips? Below is the while loop that reads the devices current status.

```
    while (true) {

            getStatus();

            try {
                    bytes = 0;
                    while(bytes < 1){

                        bytes = mmInStream.read(statusBuffer);


                        if (bytes != 0){
                            response = new String(statusBuffer);
                                            //Handle response code
                            }

                        }   
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "disconnected FROM WHILE TRUE LOOP", e);
                    connectionLost();
                    break;
                }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is no byte available, -1 is returned by read, you miss your comparison and you go on looping.

If your line ends with a \n char it would be far easier to read it through an BufferedReader for instance. Anyhow, your loop is not very well designed.

do
   {
       //read bytes
       //store the result in byteRead

```
  //if( byteRead != -1 )
  //build a string
```

}//do
   while( byteRead != -1 )

Regards,
 Stéphane

Comment: I was not able to get your code working so wrapped the read with some log info:

        Log.i(TAG, "WHILE LOOP: About to read bytes");
             bytes = mmInStream.read(statusBuffer);
             Log.i(TAG, "WHILE LOOP: " + Integer.toString(bytes) + " bytes");

But I never make it to that second log when I encounter the problem, so I can't check if it's -1 or not.

Comment: And what happens if you read one byte instead of trying to fill a buffer.

Comment: The same thing happens, I tried byteRead = mmInstream.read(); and also a one byte buffer and saw the same results.

Comment: And are you sure the server actually writes something into your socket ?

Comment: Is there a way I can verify that? Right now inside a while(true) loop I send a status request and then loop while(byteRead != -1) so even if it does not read anything it should come back around and send another status request.

Comment: trace your program, make it write stuff to the console to follow what happens

Comment: Wouldn't the log statements take care of that? I have this in place now: while(byteRead != -1){ byteRead = mmInStream.read();
                if (byteRead != -1){
                 builder = builder + (char) byteRead;
                 Log.i(TAG, "WHILE LOOP: builder value: " + builder);
                }else{
                 //We are done building string
                 Log.i(TAG, "WHILE LOOP: Completed builder value: " + builder);} }

I expect a 6 character response, and see that built char by char but once it tries to read the stream after that I do not get any further logging information.

Comment: Something is missing. Your code seems correct. You would be better isolating the code and ask a new question with all the code needed to compile a small app.

Comment: We're working with custom hardware/firmware, and this will show my ignorance a bit but is the firmware responsible for sending back the -1 or does the read() function handle it? Since my initial code worked most of the time and seemed to hang randomly I might be trying to read the status before the device is ready, and not be getting a -1 back from the device if it is responsible for that?